# OSDEV multitasking run application

Tags: assembly

i'm runs object code on my multitasking OS. There is problem: gcc compilator compiles code, that addresses variables in memory from 0. I.e. variable 'qqq' stores with offset 8 from my code start, gcc makes mov ($8),%eax, but I'm running all apps in one segment. And 2 equal apps have equals offsets from memory start(from zero). Hon I can tell linker to use variables with offset of programm start? Or some processor registers may to do it? Sorry for my English.

Comment: You can specify section base addresses using the linker, either via option `--section-start` or a linker script. See the manual.

Comment: @Jester linker don't knows, where we will be after program run.

Comment: That's why you tell it. Not sure what your exact problem is. As far as I understood you have some toy operating system that does not offer separate virtual address spaces. Hence, you need to ensure your programs don't collide. Set different section addresses. Alternatively, write all your code such that it gets a pointer to a data area during startup and reference things relative to that. But that's a code change, not a linker as you asked. Of course you could also fix your OS, either the loader or the memory management.

Comment: @Jester, I'm want gcc to do "mov variable_addr, reg" with offset of entry addr. I'm recives en try address from my os.

Comment: You'd need to keep the relocation entries for the references and have your OS loader fix them up. Obviously if you don't know the "entry addr" until runtime, the compiler and linker have no way to generate correct addresses. If you do know it at compile time, then it's back to option one: specify section start.

Comment: @Jester, or have I map virtual memory to physical without touching GDT? AND if I received variable address from malloc (), I'm will touch other memory, don't that, pointer will point to other phys memory address

Comment: You can use paging as mainstream operating systems do.

Comment: @Jester, great thanks!